# The difference of Prime in Solve doesn't work

Tags: equation-solving, prime-numbers

Can someone explain why Solve does not work with Prime difference? This cond does not work:

```
Solve[Prime[n] - Prime[m] == 8, {n, m}, Integers]
```

But you can find such n and m, the difference of which will give 8:

```
Prime[25] - Prime[24]

8
```

Sum of Prime is easy to find:

```
Solve[Prime[n] + Prime[m] == 8, {n, m}, Integers]

{{n -> 2, m -> 3}, {n -> 3, m -> 2}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a constraint to your [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve):

```
Solve[Prime[n] - Prime[m] == 8 && 0 < m < n < 100, {n, m}, Integers]
```

> {{n -> 5, m -> 2}, {n -> 6, m -> 3}, {n -> 8, m -> 5}, {n -> 11, 
>     m -> 9}, {n -> 12, m -> 10}, {n -> 18, m -> 16}, {n -> 19, 
>     m -> 17}, {n -> 22, m -> 20}, {n -> 25, m -> 24}, {n -> 29, 
>     m -> 26}, {n -> 34, m -> 32}, {n -> 37, m -> 35}, {n -> 42, 
>     m -> 40}, {n -> 46, m -> 43}, {n -> 53, m -> 51}, {n -> 58, 
>     m -> 56}, {n -> 59, m -> 57}, {n -> 73, m -> 72}, {n -> 78, 
>     m -> 77}, {n -> 80, m -> 79}, {n -> 85, m -> 83}, {n -> 88, 
>     m -> 87}, {n -> 93, m -> 92}, {n -> 95, m -> 94}}

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because there is (conjecturally) an infinite number of solutions. You can use e.g.

```
Flatten[Table[If[Prime[n] - Prime[m] == 8, {n, m}, Nothing], {n, 1, 100}, {m, 1, 100}], 1]
```

to generate the first few pairs:

```
{{5, 2}, {6, 3}, {8, 5}, {11, 9}, {12, 10}, {18, 16}, {19, 17}, {22, 20}, {25, 24},
{29, 26}, {34, 32}, {37, 35}, {42, 40}, {46, 43}, {53, 51}, {58, 56}, {59, 57},
{73, 72}, {78, 77}, {80, 79}, {85, 83}, {88, 87}, {93, 92}, {95, 94}}
```

Comment: [Nothing against your answer or reasoning, but... this also does not "work": `Solve[Prime[n] - Prime[m] == 9, {n, m}, Integers]`]

Answer (score 2):

another possible way to generate them is (for first 100 primes)

```
ClearAll[n, m, i, j, z];
z = Prime[Range[100]];
(Last@Reap@Do[ Do[If[z[[i]] - z[[j]] == 8, 
    Sow[{n -> z[[i]], m -> z[[j]]}]], {i, 1, Length@z}], {j, 1,Length@z}])[[1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly variant variant version of @AccidentalFourierTransform and @Nasser answer.

```
z = Prime[Range[100]];
Table[If[PrimeQ[z[[i]] + 8] == True, {z[[i]], z[[i]] + 8},Nothing], {i, Length@z}]
```

> {{3, 11}, {5, 13}, {11, 19}, {23, 31}, {29, 37}, {53, 61}, {59, 
>     67}, {71, 79}, {89, 97}, {101, 109}, {131, 139}, {149, 157}, {173, 
>     181}, {191, 199}, {233, 241}, {263, 271}, {269, 277}, {359, 
>     367}, {389, 397}, {401, 409}, {431, 439}, {449, 457}, {479, 
>     487}, {491, 499}}